# How to find Metadata URL of IMS Database to connect from Java when I have host name, port and Datastore name?

Tags: java, metadata, mainframe, non-relational-database, ims-db

Please someone who has idea on Metadata URL, tell me 
how can I find Metadata URL when I have host name, 
port and IMS Datastore?

I got the below information regarding Metadata URL:

The location of the database metadata representing 
the target IMS database.

The MetadataURL property is the fully qualified name 
of the Java metadata class generated by the IMS Enterprise 
Suite Explorer for Development. The URL must be prefixed 
with class:// (for example, class://com.foo.BMP255DatabaseView).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I got the solution for this problem. 

1. Download IBM Installer and DL I Utility Plugin from IBM Site
2. Install DLI Utility Plugin into your Eclipse
4. Create a sample DLI Utility Project by importing PSB and DBD Source files of 
your IMS database
5. After successful creation of the project, check inside the project, the Java 
Metadata File will be created. 
6. Use the created Java file name as Metadata URL for your Java IMS connection 
by providing the metadata file in your classpath.
```

## For more information, go to below links:

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ims.dlimodel21.doc%2Fdli_creatingnew.htm

## For downloads, go to below link:

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/ims/soa-integration-suite/enterprise-suite/dlimodel-utility/